# Saving images on different Android devices (phone and tablet)

Tags: java, android, android-sdcard, android-external-storage

The main target of app is to download from the network images using the URL. For now the image download well, the URL link works well. But the problem happens with saving the image to device storage.
1. My mobile phone has SD card and the saving works well.
2. My tablet has build in storage 16Gb. And on my tablet the images are downloads but not saved.

The example of source code to save image:

```
        FileManager fileManager = new FileManager();

        if (fileManager.fileExists(filename)) {
            File file = fileManager.getFile(filename);
            Uri fileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
            return new SaveImageRequest(fileUri);
        } else {
            String type = ".png"; //fallback to ".png"
            if (path.toString().lastIndexOf(".") != -1) { //-1 means there are no punctuations in the path
                type = path.toString().substring(path.toString().lastIndexOf("."));
            }
            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(path);
            request.setTitle(notificationTitle);
            request.setVisibleInDownloadsUi(false);
            request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE);
            request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
            request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES, "/DestinationDir/" + filename + type);

            return new SaveImageRequest(downloadManager.enqueue(request));
        }
```

Have you any solution for saving images on devices with built in storage and devices with external storage?
PS: android permissions for accessing to storage

Comment: Seems you should include your `SaveImageRequest` class

Answer (score 0):

You should check the media availability as described in the [Google Android Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal)

```
/* Checks if external storage is available for read and write */
public boolean isExternalStorageWritable() {
String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
    return true;
}
return false;
}

/* Checks if external storage is available to at least read */
public boolean isExternalStorageReadable() {
String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state) ||
    Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {
    return true;
  }
return false;
}
```